# Infernal Libraries (aka DLL Hell)

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, delphi-2010, dll

In a Project of mine, I use a Delphi Application which dynamically loads a wrapper DLL (exporting C-Style functions) which in turn is statically link against a bunch of 3rd party DLLs.

It works fine on my test machines, but on my customers computer it failed to initialize with an error Message like "Couldn't find entrypoint _somefunction@4AKKZ in TMYlibrary.dll".

After some investigation with sysinternal's process monitor, I realized that Windows would look fror DLLs in windows/sytem32 first, so if a DLL named similar to *my* DLL was present in system32, windows would pick that one and try to find my function entry points in it - which would fail.

Do you know of a possiblity to change windows' DLL the searching behaviour?

---

**Additional Information**

- [**Update**] The .exe file is located on the top level of the application's folder tree.
- The Wrapper and the 3rd-party-DLLs ar e both located in the Subfolder /bin of my apps Folder
- Dev platform is windows XP/7, using VS2008 for the dlll and Delphi 2010 for the application

Comment: Where is the EXE file located? Also in \bin folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found another solution myself:

`SetDllDirectory` adds an additional search path to the list of locations to look at.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

> After calling SetDllDirectory, the DLL search path is:
>
> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The directory specified by the lpPathName parameter.
> 3. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the
>      path of this directory. The name of
>      this directory is System32.
> 4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the
>      path of this directory, but it is
>      searched. The name of this directory
>      is System.
> 5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get
>      the path of this directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

(maybe i should do my googling before I post on SO ;)

Comment: +1 because it is always good when someone takes the time to give a correct answer, especially when he was the one who asked for it in the first place :)

Comment: someone might just google and hit this SO question. Which is useful. So it's worth asking and answering your own question.

Comment: @warren: Good point. That's actually how i came into contact with this site.

Answer (score 1):

Ship the DLL in your program's folder. (same as the exe file).

Then Windows should try your version first.

Comment: That's what he did. Did you read the question? Or did He?  The question is ambiguous and does not state where the EXE file is.